# Cannot use prisma migrate dev command after creating view

Tags: node.js, postgresql, prisma

i'm trying to create view using migration followed documentation of prisma [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/advanced-database-tasks/sql-views-postgres)
I have followed all steps
created migration using

```
npx prisma migrate dev --name create_views --create-only
```

and copied inside generated `create_views\migration.sql`

```
CREATE VIEW "Draft" AS
    SELECT "published", "title", "email", "Post"."id"
    FROM "Post", "User"
    WHERE "published" = false AND "Post"."authorId" = "User"."id";
```

I successfully created the views
but after adding the model manually to `schema.prisma`

```
model Draft {
  title     String
  id        Int     @unique
  email     String
  published Boolean
}
```

I cannot use the command

```
npx prisma migrate dev
```

this command will create Draft migration and get failed with message Draft already exists
I want to query using prisma on `Draft View` using prisma inbuilt query and not raw query and also add more tables so `npx prisma migrate dev` command won't fail

Answer (score 0):

Views in SQL are a kind of virtual table, and they have rows and columns as they are in a real table in the database. so I think you cannot create another table with the name as same in view. you can change your view's name.

Comment: i don't want to create table the view is already created with name Draft now how can i use the prisma functionality like prisma.db.Draft.findMany() as shown in the documentation to manually add Draft model